# where erased classes disappear in xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode

When I erased a class from my project **in xcode**, it somehow disappeared from my Mac.

I can't find it in the trash of the mac, I cant find it in the project folder.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I found this out the hard way too... You cannot recover it once you have deleted it via Xcode (Sucks i know)

All I can say is to write the lost class again and start using Time Machine or Xcodes built in source control to backup your files so it don't happen again in the future

Answer (score 1):

Xcode deletes files immediately. If you want to keep them, press "Remove the references" in the confirmation dialog.